# how to convert lists of lists into array in python?

Tags: python, matrix, graph

I am calculating the similarity scores for a pair of nodes in a graph, the result is a lists of lists as detailed below:
example output

```py
[[[(0, 1), 0.3666666666666667], [(0, 13), 0.3333333333333333], [(0, 20), 0.23809523809523808],
      [(0, 23), 0.30952380952380953], [(20, 23), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 31), 0.18253968253968253],
      [(20, 45), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 46), 0.23809523809523808], [(20, 81), 0.27142857142857146],
      [(22, 24), 0.39285714285714285], [(22, 45), 0.39285714285714285], [(24, 45), 0.2857142857142857],
      [(24, 80), 0.6428571428571428], [(25, 26), 1.0], [(27, 28), 0.5333333333333333], [(27, 29), 0.45000000000000007],
      [(29, 71), 0.375]]]
```

here I have each node pair similarity scores
How can i put this in matrix form with each column having nodes and rows bare the similarity score?
Any help will be much appreciated

here example output

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: You have one extra comma at the middle.

Comment: @ThePilotDude, here is just example output

Comment: @kwkt, yah extra comma separates node pairs  from its similarity scores

Comment: Is every node paired with every other node?

Comment: You seem to be having a list containing a single list, which contains 17 sub-lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will remove one external level of `[ ]`, and one of `, ,`, so we can convert it to dictionary as a step to make it in a matrix.

```
a=[[[(0, 1), 0.3666666666666667], [(0, 13), 0.3333333333333333], [(0, 20), 0.23809523809523808], [(0, 23), 0.30952380952380953],[(20, 23), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 31), 0.18253968253968253], [(20, 45), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 46), 0.23809523809523808], [(20, 81), 0.27142857142857146], [(22, 24), 0.39285714285714285], [(22, 45), 0.39285714285714285], [(24, 45), 0.2857142857142857], [(24, 80), 0.6428571428571428], [(25, 26), 1.0], [(27, 28), 0.5333333333333333], [(27, 29), 0.45000000000000007], [(29, 71), 0.375]]]
a=a[0] # remove one external level of `[ ]`
b=dict(a)
```

so we can get the value of node (n,m) as follows:

```
if (n,m) in b.keys():
    print(b[n,m])
else:
    print(None) # or Zero
```

according to the maximum dimension of nodes, it is 30 rows and 72 columns, then to convert dictionary to the array, we take the values and put it in the matrix

```
import numpy as np

a = [[[(0, 1), 0.3666666666666667], [(0, 13), 0.3333333333333333], [(0, 20), 0.23809523809523808],
     [(0, 23), 0.30952380952380953], [(20, 23), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 31), 0.18253968253968253],
     [(20, 45), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 46), 0.23809523809523808], [(20, 81), 0.27142857142857146],
     [(22, 24), 0.39285714285714285], [(22, 45), 0.39285714285714285], [(24, 45), 0.2857142857142857],
     [(24, 80), 0.6428571428571428], [(25, 26), 1.0], [(27, 28), 0.5333333333333333], [(27, 29), 0.45000000000000007],
     [(29, 71), 0.375]]]
a=a[0] # remove one external level of `[ ]`
b = dict(a)
r = 30
c = 72
Nodes = np.zeros([r, c])
for k, values in b.items():
    Nodes[k[1]][k[0]] = values
```

Now, we have the matrix Nodes, which has all the values of the original list in the position (r,c). The rest of the nodes have zeros.

Comment: First I will remove one external level of [ ], and one of , ,, so we can convert it to dictionary as a step to make it in a matrix. "how did you remove it" @Nour

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to remove the external []. `a=a[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
lst = [[[(0, 1), 0.3666666666666667], [(0, 13), 0.3333333333333333], [(0, 20), 0.23809523809523808], [(0, 23), 0.30952380952380953], [(20, 23), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 31), 0.18253968253968253], [(20, 45), 0.21428571428571427], [(20, 46), 0.23809523809523808], [(20, 81), 0.27142857142857146], [(22, 24), 0.39285714285714285], [(22, 45), 0.39285714285714285], [(24, 45), 0.2857142857142857], [(24, 80), 0.6428571428571428], [(25, 26), 1.0], [(27, 28), 0.5333333333333333], [(27, 29), 0.45000000000000007], [(29, 71), 0.375]]]

# list of nodes in the graph
nodes = set()
for (x, y), _ in lst[0]:
    nodes.add(x)
    nodes.add(y)
nodes = sorted(nodes)

# create the 2D array to store similarity
# here, -1 denotes no data
similarity = [[-1] * len(nodes) for _ in range(len(nodes))]

# fill the 2D array
for (x, y), val in lst[0]:
    similarity[nodes.index(x)][nodes.index(y)] = val
    # if you don't want symmetry, comment the next line out
    similarity[nodes.index(y)][nodes.index(x)] = val
```